# How can I use web3.js with Angular 2

Tags: web3js, javascript, angular2, typescript

I'm trying to import `Web3` to my component files which is written in `Typescript` but I couldn't make it.

I used `npm install --save web3-typescript-typings` and added

```
"include": [
    "../node_modules/web3-typescript-typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
```

to `tsconfig.json`. However I still get errors from browser's console:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1056:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3 as "@web3" from http://localhost:3000/app/exchange.component.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1056:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:486:38)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3 as "@web3" from http://localhost:3000/app/exchange.component.js
(anonymous) @ (index):18
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
Zone.run @ zone.js:141
(anonymous) @ zone.js:818
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:424
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:191
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:584
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:490
```

Can anyone shed me some lights?

Answer (score 2):

You're actually almost there.
Be sure to import the module in your component, like so:
`import Web3 from 'web3';`

Then, connect to the network:
`web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));`

Then use it like so:

`this.web3.isConnected()`

Answer (score 0):

For web3 1.0.0 & Angular 5, importing `Web3` to a component works without installing/including `web3-typescript-typings`